# How to install Wine on Red Hat?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, wine

I have downloaded the Setup from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/Source/wine-1.1.33.tar.bz2/download).

How do I install it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply install with:

```
yum install wine
```

No need for that package. That package probably contains sources, so unless you want to build from sources, a premade binary is much easier.

Comment: `yum` not found. Now what do I do?

Comment: yum not found, on Red Hat Linux? You must have done a very minimal install. Do you have `rpm` at least?

Comment: You could grab wine core for i386 here: http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/wine-core-1.0.1-1.el5.i386.rpm (I don't know your architecture, just a guess) and do `rpm -i wine-core-1.0.1-1.el5.i386.rpm`. I assume there are a ton of dependency errors you'll get, so you'll also need to install them.

Comment: yes I have `rpm`. How to install wine using `rpm`?

Comment: From here: http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/ select your version of Red Hat and architecture, then find wine-core, the main package you'll need. Expect a lot of dependency issues though, you'll need to find other rpms as well. I'd strongly advise installing yum instead.

Comment: yum tells me "No package wine available" on RedHat 6.5 64-bit (using and older version in order to replicate something for a client).